# Кодировка Base64 в js и python отличаются

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, base64

Все строки одинаковы, и байты тоже, но результат отличается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как реализовать кодировку base64 в python как в js?

код на js https://pastebin.com/qPzZkwVq
код на python https://pastebin.com/6QEbaAPC

Comment: Приведите байты строкой а не картинкой.

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: код в вопросе должен быть текстом. как и стек ошибки. а не скриншотом

Comment: Ниже вопроса нажмите кнопку "править" и сможете отредактировать ваш вопрос, вставив скопированный текст

Comment: исправил, добавил исходники

Comment: нынче читать не модно. модно смотреть видео-ролики. вот, смотрите на здоровье: [видеоурок: как выделить, скопировать и вставить текст](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57OpmoZL3Sc)

Comment: ах, да. самое главное: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score -1):

Решил проблему, строку нужно было кодировать в latin-1. а не в utf-8

Comment: В обоих случаях?

Comment: только в python

Comment: Запустив код на другой ноде можешь получить другой результат. И проверь не обрезает ли latin-1 байты.